# How to display percent values in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ui

```
 <ui:outputNumber class="slds-float_right" value=" . 
  {!loanOffer.origination_fee_in_percent}" format="0##.##%"/>
```

With this code in aura:iteration I am getting 4.75%, 1.5%, 2%, 2%.

What changes should I make to display percent values as 4.75%, 1.50%, 2.00%, 2.00%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lightning:formattedNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedNumber/example#lightningcomponentdemo:examplePercentFormatting) like so:

```
<lightning:formattedNumber value="0.02" style="percent" maximumFractionDigits="2" minimumFractionDigits="2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. with this formatting number if the value is 2. I am getting 200% and If value is 0.02, I am getting 2%. How should I get 2.00%?

Comment: Updated my answer. You just need to specify minimumFractionDigits="2". The documentation I linked you to in my answer is your friend :-)